# Is it possible to retrieve HTML element in web engine without using Javascript?

Tags: html, dom, webview, javafx, javafx-webengine

Is there a way to identify the type of the clicked element in `webView` (like Textbox/Radio/Button etc) using the `webEngine.getDocument()`?

Suppose I click on a textfield, I can get the x,y coordinates of the clicked position. Is it possible to identify the element present in that particular location? Something like the `document.elementFromPoint()` method in Javascript.

I can do it using Jquery/Javascript. But since we have access to `Document` object and its elements, is there a way to identify using JavaFX itself?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45495758/detect-hyperlink-hover-in-webview-and-print-the-link

Answer (score 8):

#### Update 2024

To access `HTMLDocumentImpl` from a modular application, when you execute the application use the following VM arguments to your `java` command:

```
--add-exports javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.dom=com.example.webclick
```

Make sure the add the exports as VM arguments and not as program arguments, e.g. in [Idea follow the VM arguments instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50938383/how-to-set-jvm-arguments-in-intellij-idea).

In the example the *module* name I have defined form my application in the application's `module-info.java` file is `com.example.webclick`.

```
module com.example.webclick {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.web;

    exports com.example.webclick;
}
```

You also need compile arguments to `javac`. In Idea that is done via the section: `Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Java Compiler` | override compiler parameters per module`.  Add your Idea project module with` Compilation options` (similar to the VM arguments used at runtime):

```
--add-exports javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.dom=com.example.webclick
```

Once the appropriate compile and runtime switches are used the application provided in the original answer will continue to function in modern Java and JavaFX versions (tested with OpenJDK 21.0.2 and JavaFX 21.0.2).

Other build environments, such as other IDEs and different runtime environments will have different methods of specifying the VM arguments and compiler arguments required for this feature to work.  Consult the relevant documentation for your chosen toolset (if it differs from the Idea tool information provided here).

#### Update 2022

Post JDK 8 when this answer was written the JDK has been modularised.  To access some of the APIs referenced here you need to require the appropriate modules in your `module-info.java` if you have a modular application.

Various modules involved:

- `javafx.web` for the JDK web engine.
- `jdk.xml.dom` for the `org.w3c.com.html` package.
- `java.xml` for the `org.w3c.dom` package.

The related packages and their associated modules is documented in more detail at:

- [`org.w3c.dom` package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.xml/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html).

Which references the relevant packages for Java APIs to handle HTML, XML, CSS, Events, document traversal, XPath processing, etc.

Do note that the same functionality is also available by querying the DOM from javascript embedded in a web page loaded by the WebEngine.  For most developers, the JavaScript APIs will be more convenient and functional APIs to use than the Java APIs referenced here.  The JavaScript APIs may also be used indirectly via supporting JavaScript libraries such as jquery which greatly simplifies the processing of the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction).

#### Original Answer

You can probably use the [Java Language Binding for Dom Level 2 events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/java-binding.html) on the document retrieved from the WebEngine.  These are bindings to access the same functionality as the [JavaScript event bindings](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/ecma-script-binding.html) that people use when programming events for web pages in browsers.

The referenced classes are [shipped with the JDK](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/events/package-summary.html).

Just make sure the document is fully loaded (by monitoring the [worker state](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html) or the [document property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#documentProperty)) before accessing it.

*Note:* The particular method you reference in your question [`document.elementFromPoint()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#dom-document-elementfrompoint), is not part of the DOM level 2 specification, but is instead defined as an extension to the Document Interface in the CSSOM View Module which "provide authors with a way to inspect and manipulate the visual view of a document".  Whilst the DOM level 2 specification is implemented in the JDK with the org.w3c module, the CSSOM View Module extensions are not.

---

OK, so this next part is a bit off-reservation as it is not documented in the official standard JDK Javadoc.  So caveats, such as, "may not apply to all JavaFX implementations" or "may not always be supported by or Oracle" or "may break in future Java versions" apply.  But anyway, on to the interesting stuff...

The document property in WebView is actually an implementation of the [org.w3c.dom.html.HTMLDocument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/plugin/dom/org/w3c/dom/html/HTMLDocument.html) interface which is documented at this weird location: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/plugin.  This interface and all of the supporting Java HTML document modeling classes are shipped with Oracle Java Runtime 8 along with JavaFX.  The HTMLDocument interface and associated classes form a far richer API than the plain org.w3c.Document interfaces documented in the standard JDK documentation.

So you could cast the document to a HTMLDocument and you would get more functionality.

However, even then, there is lots of functionality in a browser (and a WebView document) that isn't exposed by a pure HTMLDocument interface.

So, you can get at this "hidden" functionality, by casting the document to a `com.sun.webkit.dom.HTMLDocumentImpl`.  Then you expose a veritable orgy of APIs.

So let's do that... here I capture a mouse event over a HTML div element.

[image: sample inspection]

This is a (really) simple web inspector, like Firebug.  Mouse over an element in a JavaFX WebView and some minimal info on the element will be displayed in a JavaFX Label at the top of the screen.

```
import com.sun.webkit.dom.HTMLDocumentImpl;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.w3c.dom.events.MouseEvent;

public class WebViewClicker extends Application {

    public static final String LOC =
            "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31957218/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-html-element-in-web-engine-without-using-javascript";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Label elementInfo = new Label();
        WebView webview = new WebView();

        webview.getEngine().documentProperty().addListener((observable, oldDoc, newDoc) -> {
            HTMLDocumentImpl realMcCoy = (HTMLDocumentImpl) newDoc;
            realMcCoy.setOnmousemove(event -> {
                MouseEvent expertMouser = (MouseEvent) event;

                elementInfo.setText(
                        realMcCoy.elementFromPoint(
                                expertMouser.getClientX(),
                                expertMouser.getClientY()
                        ).toString()
                );
            });
        });

        webview.getEngine().load(LOC);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(
                new VBox(
                        elementInfo,
                        webview
                )
        ));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

You might notice that even your desired `elementFromPoint` method is available...  though it isn't strictly needed here, as you could just get the event target directory from the expert mouser.

The sample just treats the retrieved element as a standard w3c dom element, which has (for me) a particularly cryptic API.  However you can cast the element to an appropriate [com.sun.webkit.dom.HTMLElementImpl subclass](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/9-dev/rt/file/tip/modules/web/src/main/java-wrappers/com/sun/webkit/dom) to get more easily accessible functionality and a nicer, more direct API that reflects something that you might be used to when you work with the HTML DOM using JavaScript.

Comment: If I do, event.getTarget() returns me WebView everytime wherever I click. So, I'm not able to map particular elements.

Comment: When I ran your program I get an error like how I can fix error: cannot access XPathEvaluator
            realMcCoy.setOnmousemove(event -> {
  class file for org.w3c.dom.xpath.XPathEvaluator not found

Comment: @MaTâm I tried running the program and it worked fine with no errors (jdk1.8.0_72 on OS X 10.9.5).  I do not know why you it does not work for you Ma.

Comment: I use the latest NetBean and jdk1.8.0_91 under Windows 7.it appears the following error => cannot access XPathEvaluator
            realMcCoy.setOnmousemove(event -> {
  class file for org.w3c.dom.xpath.XPathEvaluator not found

Comment: HTMLDocumentImpl is no longer accessible in the java module system.

Comment: @codeDr You can provide compile and runtime switches to allow the `HTMLDocumentImpl` to be accessed from your application code (see update in the answer for info on how to do that using the Idea IDE).

Comment: @jewelsea I really like this solution as it makes it easy to get the html element under the mouse.

Comment: @codeDr Yes, I agree.  There is a lot of hidden, undocumented functionality in the `com.sun.webkit.dom` package.  You can manipulate the document object model (the DOM) in Java the same as you can do in JavaScript via the [JavaScript DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API).  A quarter of a century ago, the HTML DOM API was defined as a language neutral specification with bindings in both Java and JavaScript.  Use of the Java interfaces fell out of favor to JavaScript interfaces.  In a better world, the Java interface would be documented and made public.