# How can I detect clicks on a JavaFX WebView from the main application?

Tags: scala, javafx, webview, event-handling

Currently I do this by adding a Javascript event handler to the HTML content which sets a global variable according to the clicked item:

```
<script>
  var clicked="";
</script>

<span onmousedown="clicked='me';">me</span>
```

then from the main application I query the content of this variable in the webview's mouse clicked handler:

```
webview.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler[MouseEvent]{
  def handle(mouseEvent:MouseEvent){
    if(mouseEvent.getEventType().toString()=="MOUSE_CLICKED"){

       val clicked=webview.executeScript("clicked").toString()

}}})
```

This happens to work but it feels like a hack. Is there a legitimate way by which the webview can request the application to refresh its content based on the element that was clicked?

Comment: Your second code block is not valid Java. Is it Scala? If so you should mention it. If I understood you correctly you want to be notified in you application code when a HTML element was clicked and not if there was a click anywhere in the webview? From your example I gather that the content of the page is under your control and you can change it?

Comment: I use JavaFX from Scala. The HTML is generated by me and when the user clicks on some element, a new content should be generated, also by me. Everything is completely under my control. I wonder if the HTML can send a sort of HTTP request to the main application when an element is clicked with the application playing the role of the server. Or whether I can detect that the WebView is about to load a new content from an url, stop this process and based this url load my own content ( this way I could use hrefs with dummy urls that contain information as to which element was clicked ).

Comment: See related: [Is it possible to retrieve HTML element in web engine without using Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31957218/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-html-element-in-web-engine-without-using-javascript)

Comment: This is interesting, I will look into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I do not know Scala, I can only provide you with an approach in Java, but you can probably figure out, how to transform it to Scala.
Register a bridge between the Java (or in your case Scala) code and JavaScript. The basics are described in [this article](https://blogs.oracle.com/javafx/entry/communicating_between_javascript_and_javafx) by Oracle. The JavaScript in your page can make a call to the application, notifying it that a certain button was clicked:

```
public class MyBridge {
  public void callbackFromJavaScript(String what) {
     ...
  }
}

JSObject jsobj = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
jsobj.setMember("java", new MyBridge());
```

Then you can make the call when an element is clicked and `callbackFromJavaScript` will be executed:

```
<span onmousedown="java.callbackFromJavaScript('me');">me</span>
```

From your `callbackFromJavaScript` you can then easily call a JavaScript function and pass along an object (e.g. JSON) and the JS function will update the page, or you can load a completely different content.