# How to set JVM arguments in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jvm-arguments

I am confused about the instruction when using Kinesis Video Stream

> Run DemoAppMain.java in ./src/main/demo with JVM arguments set to
>
> ```
> -Daws.accessKeyId={YourAwsAccessKey} -Daws.secretKey={YourAwsSecretKey} -Djava.library.path={NativeLibraryPath}
> ```
>
> for non-temporary AWS credential.

How to set these arguments in IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Intellij allows you to specify two types of arguments when running a Java program:

- VM Options

  - Enables you to modify attributes of the JVM, including stack/heap memory allocation, system properties, GC flags, etc.
- Program Arguments

  - Values entered here are passed into the `String[]` parameter of your main method when the program begins.

[image]

In the above image, we specify a single system property (under VM Options) named `example` that has a value of `Hello World!`.

We also specify two program arguments (under Program Arguments): `Hello` and `World!`.

After clicking either the `Apply` button or the `OK` button, we can run the following program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("example"));
    System.out.println(args[0] + " " + args[1]);
}
```

The output of this program is as follows:

```
Hello World!
Hello World!
```

To create a Run/Debug Configuration, see: [Create and Edit Run/Debug Configurations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html)

Comment: any example for passing them?

Comment: @gaurav I’ll edit this answer later today to make it more clear.

Comment: does VM options accept comma seperated list? Or spaces like on the command line?

Comment: @GeoffLangenderfer - from the Intellij documentation: "Options are separated using spaces. If an option has spaces inside, enclose it in double quotes. If double quotes is a part of an option, escape them using backslash..."

Comment: Modern Idea versions (as of 2023), have slightly changed the UI for configuring the VM options from the screenshot here. The screenshot in [m19v's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67960821/1155209), is more descriptive in setting the VM options for the current Idea version.

Answer (score 89):

Follow steps below if you have 2021.1.1 Community Version:

[image]

Comment: I am also working on using `Jep` in my Android app and found on the [IntelliJ docs.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#configure-jvm-options) that we could `help` on the top menu bar and `Edit Custom VM Options...`. I guess we can also add it here ?

Comment: It's really hard to discover, why don't they just call it JVM args like everybody? It used to be that, I believe. VM options doesn't seem like it, plus it's not even shown by default. Kinda disappointed, usually JetBrains offers a great experience.

Answer (score 1):

go to edit configuration and put

```
-Dserver.port=9006(required port no)
```

in the VM options: and apply and run, it will work

Answer (score 0):

[image]You can add multiple VM arguments

```
-Dserver.port=8999 -Dapi.prediction.base.url=https://ags-qa-predictions.azur -Dlogging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate=DEBUG -Dspring.jpa.show-sql=true -Dspring.profiles.active=prod
```