# How to launch openjfx 11 app on Intellij Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, openjfx, javafx-11

I am using openjfx 11 with java 11.

If I launch the app with mvn, it works fine. I have those dependencies added:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
    <version>11</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
    <version>11</version>
</dependency>
```

But if I run within Intellij Idea (2018.2), it gives me:

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

IntelliJ idea adds the jars to classpath.

Comment: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467561/intellij-cant-recognize-javafx-11-with-openjdk-11/52470141#52470141) on how to set IntelliJ and the Maven project

Comment: I saw the answer but it does not address running the app from intellij without manually setting a separated (from maven) sdk folder.

Comment: Yes it does, via adding the required maven plugins to your pom. Then you can run the `exec:java` goal (see bullet points 4, 5).

Comment: But running the maven goal is not the same as running through intellij idea. Or is it? Can I debug running like this?

Comment: Yes, you can run and debug from IntelliJ through the Maven Projects window.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking, I have found the answer here (not specific to Intellij)
:
http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2018-October/022675.html

Answer (score 1):

### There are 2 ways:

---

The first one is to pass 
 `--module-path=PATHTOOPENJFX/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml` 
arguments to java

---

The second one: 
Create new class, make it main and call main() of the class that extends Application

```
package sample;
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            YourClass.main(args);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do i pass this in IntelliJ

Comment: @user3801839 this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50938383/how-to-set-jvm-arguments-in-intellij

Comment: Why does it work with the extra main-class (Main) but not directly with the original class (YourClass)?