# InteliJ JavaFX: Javafx.controls not found

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I'm dealing with an odd problem in IntelliJ. I'm working on creating a desktop application that makes fairly extensive use of JavaFX and though the program is finished, it simply will not run in IntelliJ. The code compiles and runs in Eclipse but not in Intellij no matter what I do or what settings I configure.

#### The error I keep getting is:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found
```

This error never appeared in the Eclipse IDE during compile so I'm at a bit of a lose to explain its presence here.

#### What I've done to fix it.

The first thing I checked was I made sure that the *project structure* was configured correctly. I went into the libraries tab and added the *lib* folder and added the same *VM options* I used for Eclipse. [OpenJFX: JavaFX and IntelliJ IDEA](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/)

Project Structure
[image]

VM Options
[image]

I also tried deleting the files and re-downloading them into a new project from GitHub but that simply gave me the same result.

The only other thing I can think of as a potential problem is that there are a lot of files in here from Eclipse and I'm not sure if that's the cause of the problem or not. I couldn't find anything to corroborate that theory so I'm not sure.

Comment: You configured program arguments not VM options, see the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67960821/1155209) for the correct way to configure VM options.

Comment: I advise creating a new project using [new JavaFX project wizard](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/new-project-wizard.html), it is easier or more reliable than setting this up manually, plus it will enable a build tool like maven or gradle with the appropriate project directory structure and module setup, so it is a much better approach than what you are trying to do (which is a weird mix of maven and manually setup libraries) IMO.