# Spring profiling not works for application.properties

Tags: java, spring

I want to set default profile=prod (when the project executes from the ci-cd on the server) and profile=local when I execute a project from intellij idea.

There is application.properties file:

```
spring.profiles.active=prod

#Database settings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ddauth
...
```

There is application-local.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://172.17.0.2:3306/ddauth
```

there is I set `spring.profiles.active` parameter in IntellijIdea Run configuration:

[image]

I also try to execute my jar file with a such parameter:

`java -jar app.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=local`

In any case, the project is executing in the `prod` mode. I receive following message during execution:

`2023-08-01 23:02:52 [INFO] | AuthRunner:640  The following 1 profile is active: "prod"`

I read many different tutorials and haven't any ideas how it has to work. I know I can set this profile parameter also in the `bootJar` task, but I don't want to go through this way. I want implement this simple solution and figured out why it isn't work.

Comment: Are you sure it needs to be `-D`? Can you try just `--spring.profiles.active=`? Also, for IDEA you can specify it directly as "Profile" field if you configure the module as a Spring project

Comment: @IgorArtamonov thanks, but this option also doesn't work. I am a little bit confused...does it mean that I try the correct way but it doesn't work for me? Maybe the reason is the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `-Dspring.profiles.active=local` as a JVM argument.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't seen this possibility in my configuration but found here how to add it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50938383/how-to-set-jvm-arguments-in-intellij-idea

Comment: at first I was hella confused as I thought OP already passed `-Dspring.profiles.active=local`, but OP was passing it as a _program argument_ not _JVM argument_