# Unsupported size for JarEntry META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

Tags: java, spring, maven

When I try to compile my Spring app with Maven in Java 11 I get this error:

> java: error reading /home/danny/.m2/repository/com/groupdocs/groupdocs-metadata/18.4/groupdocs-metadata-18.4.jar; Unsupported size: 8510995 for JarEntry META-INF/MANIFEST.MF. Allowed max size: 8000000 bytes

I have bundled Maven 3.9.2 in InteliJ.

What should I change in InteliJ to run this?

Comment: a size of 8MB for `MANIFEST.MF` is something really weird. Can you open and inspect the file?

Comment: @Grim why, what's the relevance of the pom?

Comment: @f1sh I downloaded the file and the MANIFEST.MF is indeed 8.510.995 bytes big.

Comment: That is something related to security issues in JDK: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8312489, https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/17-0-8-relnotes.html#JDK-8300596

Comment: What have you searched for on the internet so far?

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by a [feature released in JDK17.0.8](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/17-0-8-relnotes.html#JDK-8300596):

> A new system property, jdk.jar.maxSignatureFileSize, has been added to allow applications to control the maximum size of signature files in a signed JAR. The value of the system property is the desired size in bytes. The default value is 8000000 bytes.

That means you can fix your problem using `-Djdk.jar.maxSignatureFileSize=16000000` or something else that is bigger than 8M.

[Andrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3426309/andrey-b-panfilov)'s [link above](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8312489) (in the comments) points to this being a regression in the JDK and the default value will be 16M in a future JDK release:

> Follow-up to a July 2023 security fix which introduced a default maximum signature size of 8MB, that turned out to be a little too low in real world usage. This fix just doubles the default to 16MB.

Comment: Good catch to check jdk-bugs. This will fix the problem for **this** jar. It might be reoccour if a MANIFEST.MF size exceed again. So, it is not a good solution but it will make it this time.

Comment: As I said: you can increase the size to anything you want, fixing this problem permanently. How is that not a good solution?

Comment: Your solution is perfect, that such limitation to the MANIFEST.MF increaes instead to remove the limitation basically is a bad solution of the JDK-developers. You are fine.

Comment: It's definitely a weird decision to implement this limit out of nowhere. An 8M MANIFEST.MF should be looked into, but it shouldn't prevent your application from running at all when it all worked fine with the previous JDK version.

Comment: @f1sh Unfortunately that doesn't work for me. I am using  Amazon Corretto java in version 11.0.20

Answer (score 1):

For me what worked in Windows + Amazon Corretto jdk 11.0.20 was to set the **JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS** as a system environment variable:

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djdk.jar.maxSignatureFileSize=22000000
```

I've also tried this approach - it worked once, then somehow all the further invocations threw the Unsupported size Exception when opened IntelliJ next time. So I switched back to **JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS**
[How to set JVM arguments in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50938383/how-to-set-jvm-arguments-in-intellij-idea)