# groupdocs word file merge issue

Tags: aspose.words, groupdocs

I am using following code for Word file merge using groupdocs merge.

```java
String filePath1 = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\1.docx";
String filePath2 = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\2.docx";
String filePathOut = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\result.docx";

Merger merger = new Merger(filePath1);

merger.join(filePath2);
merger.save(filePathOut);
```

Above code I am using for document merge but it is giving following error.

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: java.io.IOException: Unsupported size: 14650052 for JarEntry META-INF/MANIFEST.MF. Allowed max size: 8000000 bytes
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unsupported size: 14650052 for JarEntry META-INF/MANIFEST.MF. Allowed max size: 8000000 bytes
```

Same error occurred when I deploy groupdocs-merger-23.10.jar to tomcat.

Comment: It looks like you have the same problem as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77164013/unsupported-size-for-jarentry-meta-inf-manifest-mf