# Error in module system when registering controlsFX validator for combo box in JavaFX project

Tags: java, validation, javafx, controlsfx, module-info

I'm trying to register ControlsFX validator for a ComboBox in JavaFX. Then, I got the below error relating to the module system. When I try to open javafx.scene package to the org.controlsfx.controls module, it also resulted in an error. I'll add all the codes and errors I got below.

This is my code which is causing the error.

```
ValidationSupport validationSupport = new ValidationSupport();
validationSupport.registerValidator(prefixCombo, Validator.createEmptyValidator("Combobox selection required!"));
```

This is the error I got when running the project.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected javafx.collections.ObservableList javafx.scene.Parent.getChildren() accessible: module javafx.graphics does not "opens javafx.scene" to module org.controlsfx.controls
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
```

This is my current module-info.java file

```
module system {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires jakarta.persistence;
    requires org.hibernate.orm.core;
    requires MaterialFX;
    requires org.slf4j;
    requires de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome;
    requires static lombok;
    requires org.controlsfx.controls;
    requires javafx.graphics;


    opens com.example.system to javafx.fxml, org.controlsfx.controls;
    exports com.example.system;
    exports com.example.system.controller;
    opens com.example.system.controller to javafx.fxml, javafx.graphics;
    opens com.example.system.entity to org.hibernate.orm.core;
    opens com.example.system.tm to javafx.base;
}
```

I tried adding `opens javafx.scene to org.controlsfx.controls;` to module-infor.java.
Then, resulted in another error `Package not found: javafx.scene`

Thank you all in advance!!

Comment: See [Using ControlsFX with JDK 9 and above](https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx/wiki/Using-ControlsFX-with-JDK-9-and-above).  It doesn't address you exact issue, but shows you how similar issues are addressed with other ControlsFX components.

Comment: Thank you @jewelsea for sharing the link. It gave valuable insights into similar issues. Although it didn't directly address my specific problem, the information was helpful in understanding related challenges. Your guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an [`opens`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/module/ModuleDescriptor.Opens.html) directive in the `module-info` pertains to opening a package of the module **`system`**(your module) to another module specified i.e `org.controlsfx.controls`. Hence, the expected compilation error, since your application module doesn't include the package mentioned.

What you are looking for is the command line argument that could help you provide access to `javafx.scene` package from module `javafx.graphics` for your runtime option i.e.

```
--add-opens javafx.graphics/javafx.scene=org.controlsfx.controls
```

**Note** - Keep in mind this shall only be [considered a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43043879/1746118).

Comment: I encountered an issue when following the provided instruction `--add-opens javafx.graphics/javafx.scene=org.controlsfx.controls` in IntelliJ IDEA to resolve the exception. Despite adding this VM option, the problem persisted. It seems that this workaround did not address the issue as expected. Thank you for your assistance, but I am still facing the same error even after implementing the suggested command line argument.

Comment: @JananiBalasooriya make sure you are accurately [setting VM options in Idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50938383/how-to-set-jvm-arguments-in-intellij-idea) and not program arguments (just something to check, I don't know that it is your actual issue).

Comment: @jewelsea Thank you for your suggestion to check the VM options in IntelliJ IDEA instead of program arguments. It turned out that I had mistakenly set program arguments instead of VM options, and after correcting this, the issue has been resolved. Your input was valuable in identifying and rectifying the misconfiguration.