# JavaFX runtime components not found despite CLI arguments

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

When trying to run my program I get the following error:

`JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application`

I have added the following CLI arguments to my run configuration (as well as the library in the project structure):

```
--module-path "C:\<path>\javafx-sdk-21.0.2\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

but the issue persists and I'm unsure as to why. I've done, as far as I'm aware, all that the OpenJFX guide asks for: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/. I use intellij and want to run my non-modular project from the IDE.

Thank you.

Edit:
Intellij is slightly confusing when it comes to programs arguments vs VM arguments, as pointed out in the comments. I instead added the above arguments to VM options and everything worked.

Comment: The [Maven JavaFX plugin](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin) makes this easy

Comment: Why use the CLI arguments if you bundled the necessary libraries within your own JAR?

Comment: You probably added arguments as [program arguments instead of VM arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50938383/how-to-set-jvm-arguments-in-intellij-idea), so you didn't do what you thought you did.  Idea is confusing in this way.