Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=250m'
I am using Intellij Idea and working on different maven projects(JDK-8, JDK-17), whenever I try to run mvn clean install for any of the different projects I am getting this error
"Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=250m'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine"

I have checked everywhere where VM options can be specified but no where it is mentioned.
I took help of ChatGPT as well and checked for every possible place where VM options are mentioned but didnt find any

Does this answer your question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50938383

Hi Stephen, sadly NO. I havent added any VM options nor there are any existing VM options which are set but still I am getting the error

What about this?  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000421640-How-to-remove-MaxPermSize-from-run-configuration-VM-options
